# Rails 3 - jQuery returned from AJAX call is not being evaluated

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have a Rails 3 form with :remote => true, like this:

```
<%= form_for :line_item, :url => line_items_path(:product_id => product), :remote => true do |f| %>
    <%= f.submit "Add to Cart" %>      
<% end -%>
```

Then in my view file, create.js.erb, I have some jQuery code:

```
$('#cart').html('test')
```

The Net tab in Firebug shows that this code does get returned, but it doesn't do anything. As if it's not getting evaluated. I have the jquery-rails gem installed. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mast rename the file to create.rjs and to write in file

```
page << "$('#cart').html('test')"
```

Comment: And check your rails.js in public/javascripts. Content should be for jquery framework.

Comment: How would I embed Ruby into the .html() function using the 'page << ' method?

Comment: This solution works and I got my original code in my .js.erb file to work too.